# docker-compose connecting to other container fails

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have two docker images, one rest server (`flaskapp`) and another web server (`web`). I am trying to run them using `docker-compose`.

However, it seems that the **web container** is not able to contact the **rest container**

Following is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  flaskapp:
    build: ./rest_server
    restart: always
    networks:
      - docker_network
    expose:
      - 5001

  web:
    build: ./web
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3002:3000
    depends_on:
      - flaskapp
    networks:
      - docker_network
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://flaskapp:5001/todos"]
networks:
  docker_network:
    driver: bridge
```

My web application refers to the following URL:

> http://flaskapp:5001/todos

However, If I log to docker container using `docker exec -it <id> /bin/bash` and run the following command I get the json response I expect.

> curl http://flaskapp:5001/todos

I can expose my rest server port as well, and then change the rest server address to localhost in web server and this will resolve the issue, however this is not what I would like.

I don't want to expose my rest server to host machine.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean when you say: "the web container is not able to contact the rest container". What error do you have?

Comment: If you use 5433:5432 it won't expose 5433 port, and you will get connection refused. As soon as you change it to "5433:5432" it will work. Tested with the official postgres:13.2 image(13 as well).

Answer (score 3):

You need to:

1. define a common network for your containers
2. expose the port `5001` of your `flaskapp` container

Indeed, according to the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/expose), the `EXPOSE` instruction "exposes ports without publishing them to the host machine - they’ll only be accessible to linked services". So it allows communication between the container which "expose" the port, and other containers in the same network.

Try something like that:

```
version: '3'
services:
    flaskapp:
        build: ./rest_server
        expose:
            - 5001
        networks:
            - docker_network

    web:
        build: ./web
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 3002:3000
        networks:
            - docker_network
        depends_on:
            - flaskapp

networks:
  docker_network:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: I am still getting the same result. I defined the networking. `networks:
    docker_network:
        driver: bridge`

Comment: no, I don't have any error message and status is healthy

Answer (score 1):

just add:

```
expose:
 - "5001"
```

to flaskapp section.

This doesn't expose the port: 5001 to the host, this simply exposes port 5001 to all the containers in the same network, which is what you want.

Comment: same result, I can access the rest server from within the web container. however when the rest server send the request it fails. it's weird though.

Comment: sounds like it has something to do with your web container then. The container environment is setup correctly. I guess next step is to see if the web container accepts CORS request. Because they essentially resides in two places.