# docker nginx proxy to linked container not working

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, reverse-proxy

I have tried this:
[NGINX reverse proxy not working to other docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55058427/nginx-reverse-proxy-not-working-to-other-docker-container)

and this:
[Docker nginx-proxy : proxy between containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40293757/docker-nginx-proxy-proxy-between-containers)

and followed nginx config from here:
[nginx proxy_pass to a linked docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28028789/nginx-proxy-pass-to-a-linked-docker-container)

I am simply trying to tell nginx to proxy to a linked api service **on port `4000`**. I do not want to expose `4000` to host machine because there will be multiple services running on this port.

This is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```yml
version: '3'
services:
   api:
     build: ./api
     image: myapi:latest
     container_nameE: api
   api_nginx:
     image: nginx:latest
     container_name: api_nginx
     depends_on:
       - api
     links:
       - api
     ports:
       - "80:80"
     environment:
       - NGINX_SERVER_NAME:localhost
     volumes:
       - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
...
...
```

and my nginx server is super minimal:

```
upstream backend {
   server api;
}
server {
   listen 80;
   listen [::]:80;
   server_name ${NGINX_SERVEE_NAME};
   location / {
      resolver 127.0.0.1;
      proxy_pass http://backend/$1;
   }
}
```

This is the error is throwing:

```
...[error] 20#20: *1 no resolver defined to resolve api, client: 172.23.0.1, server: ${nginx_server_name}....
```

and the page shows a `502 Bad Gateway`

What is going on? I've followed other people's nginx configs and it's not working, I have no idea.

Comment: Both services need to share a common network to be addressed by their names. Create a network and add it to your containers, as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/54411790/4632951

Comment: @AndrewMorozko Both containers are on the `default` network; you don't need to manually declare anything for inter-container networking to work (and you don't need `links:` either).  [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation has more details.

Comment: David is correct, you don't seem to need them. I could've sworn there was some issue that required manually creating a network, but it seems like it was resolved.

Comment: @AndrewMorozko  without the link it still gives same error, I am going to try that network thing that andrew posted even though you said i might not need it, I'll give that a shot

Comment: @DavidMaze nope, same error adding the bridge network in that  other question andrew posted. It's still saying `1 no resolver defined to resolve api...` I think it's something to do with my nginx config?